# How many ways can a number be summed to from known elements

Tags: summation

In how many ways can I sum elements $a,b,c,d,...$ such that they add up to $n$?

For example, $1,2,3$ can be summed to $4$ in $4$ ways because:

$$4 = 1+1+1+1 = 2+2 = 1+3 = 2+1+1$$

If two ways use the same values but in other order (e.g. $1+2+1$) they will be counted as the same one.

Comment: look at the partition formula in wikipedia.

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy answer.

Comment: @Yassir: this question is more difficult than ordinary partitions.

Comment: oh, i didn't read the question carefully @YvesDaoust

Comment: @JMoravitz: no, $4$ is not allowed as a term.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see that now.  The question still remains though for clarification, does $2+1+1$ count as the "same" as $1+2+1$ or are they actually different?

Comment: @JMoravitz: yes, this is an important distinction. Interestingly, for the ordinary partitions, if order does not matter, the problem is arduous. And if order matters, it becomes very easy.

Comment: If $2+1+1$ is considered the same as $1+2+1$ then the given example of $1,2,3$ being summed to $n$ can be seen via generating functions as the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\dots)$.  If they are treated as different, then the number of ways $1,2,3$ can be summed to $n$ can be seen via recurrence relations with the Tribonacci sequence with initial conditions $f(-2)=f(-1)=0, f(0)=1$, and recurrence $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)+f(n-3)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have k elements, you can calculate it in $O(kn)$ steps and $O(n)$ memory.
First $W(m,1)$ is how many ways just $a$ can sum to $m$, for all numbers $1\le m\le n$.  $W(m,1)=W(m-a,1)$.
Second  $W(m,2)$ uses just $a$ and $b$, $W(m,2)=W(m,1)+W(m-b,2)$. At this point you can throw away $W(m,1)$.
$W(m,3)=W(m,2)+W(m-c,3)$
Etc.

Comment: Are you sure about the $O(kn)$ steps ?

Comment: Yes, we find each $W(m,h)$ in $O(1)$ steps by lookup.  We don't recalculate $W(m,h-1)$ or $W(m-c,h)$.  We start with low values and build up, not the other way.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your $W$. And I am pretty sure that you are wrong.

Comment: Likewise.  It is the number of ways to sum to $m$ using just the first $h$ elements.

Comment: With $a=1,b=2$, $W(m,1)=(1,1,1,1); W(m,2)=(1,2,2,3);W(m-2,2)=(0,0,1,2)$ hence $W(m,2)\ne W(m,1)+W(m-2,2)$ for $m=2$. (Also $W(m,1)\ne W(m-1,1)$ for $m=1$.)

Comment: $W(0,h)=1$ is the number of ways to have no terms.  Sorry I didn't put in the boundary conditions

Comment: And what for negative sums ? What is $W(-1,1)$ ?

Comment: You are allowed no 2s.  You are not allowed fewer, or 3+3-2 would be another partition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126459/discussion-between-empy2-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: What is $W(-1,1)$ ?

Comment: W(-m,h) are all zero.  m=0 is a boundary, or initial condition, to which the rexursion doesn't apply

Comment: My bet is that these limit cases are enough to break the method.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of work done by Ramanujan on this.

What you are looking for is called a "[partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)#:%7E:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20the%20partition,a%20non%2Dnegative%20integer%20n.&text=For%20instance%2C%20whenever%20the%20decimal,will%20be%20divisible%20by%205.)" which has no closed form expression. A lot of work was done (and is being done) and it mostly involves complex analysis and generating functions.

See for further reading and a solid textbook this book by [G. E. Andrews](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/theory-of-partitions/7BC70DD4C1A06AA6179CEDEAD2F0C2DC).

Edit:
I looked through the textbook, and the generating function of the function $p(n) =  \textrm{ nrways to partition } n \textrm{ from } i_1, i_2,... i_k$ is given by
$\prod_{i_j} \frac{1}{(1-x^{i_j})}$
where each term is often denoted $(0:i_j)$.

Comment: As I wrote in comments, this is not the ordinary partition function.

Comment: @YvesDaoust indeed, but work on the generating function of what you are looking for is also covered in the above book. It is not the standard partition function, but it is most definatelly a partition function. I believe chapter 4 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Seems to be called a "restricted partition" in the general sense (because there are yet specialized versions of the restrictions).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed. I took a course in this a few years ago, and we covered multiple different cases of restricted partitions. How many ways is there to partition a number such that the elements of the partition are 2 apart. 3 apart. etc etc

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive program to compute it starts with sorting the potential summands from largest to smallest.  If you want the number of ways to sum to $10$ from $1,2,3$ you can write it as the number of ways to sum to $10-3=7$ from $3,2,1$ plus the number of ways to sum to $10$ from $2,1$.  Each problem is simpler, so the recursion will terminate.

Comment: This method enumerates all decompositions explicitly and this an exponential process. Can we do better ?